# POST var_dump not showing anything

Tags: php

I'm obviously missing something as.

When I'm trying to post from a form using method POST and var_dumping the results I'm not getting anything back should the var_dump be showing me an array containing the form data?

here's my code so far:

```
<?php 

    include "./includes/config.php";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        //mysql_query("");");

    header('Location: ./manage_adduser.php');
    exit();
    }
?>

</head>
<body>

<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>

<div class="adminWrapper">

<div class="adminContentWrapper">
    <h1><b>Add a User</b></h1>

    <div class="list">


        <table class="addNewTable">

            <tr>
                <td class="addNewLabelRow">

                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        <label>User privileges: </label>

                            </td>
                            <td class="addNewFieldRow">

                        <select name="newUserLevel">
                            <option value=\"1\"  >(1) Standard User</option>
                            <option value=\"2\"  >(2) Moderator</option>
                            <option value=\"3\"  >(3) Admin</option>
                        </select>

                </td>

            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td class="addNewLabelRow">
                        <label>User Login Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="addNewFieldRow">
                        <input type="name" name="newUserLogin" value="">

                </td>
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td class="addNewLabelRow">
                        <label>Users Full Name: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="addNewFieldRow">
                            <input type="name" name="newUserName" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>                   

            <tr>
                <td class="addNewLabelRow">
                        <label>Users e-mail address: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="addNewFieldRow">
                            <input type="email" name="newUserEmail" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>   

        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="list">

        <table class="addNewTable">

            <tr>
                <td class="addNewLabelRow">
                        <label>Password: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="addNewFieldRow">
                            <input type="password" name="newUserPassword" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td class="addNewLabelRow">
                        <label>Repeat Password: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td class="addNewFieldRow">
                            <input type="password" name="newUserPasswordRepeat" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>                           
        </table>

    </div>

</div>

<!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="buttonWrap">
        <input class="buttonAddNewGroup" type="submit" value=" Add User ">
    </div>
```

Comment: `exit()` if `$_POST`.... Obviously

Comment: can't understand your idea the `var_dump($_POST);` will never be executed as you are using `exit()` if the method is 'POST'!!!!

Comment: This should be closed as typographycal error, don't feed. He has all information to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you're redirecting the browser if the request method is post and you lose the POST-contents.

Comment out this part:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    //mysql_query("");");

header('Location: ./manage_adduser.php');
exit();
}
```

and `var_dump($_POST)` will look different.

Comment: or put `!=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 2):

The `var_dump` is not executed, because you are exiting your code before that statement:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    /* … */
    exit();
}
```

Comment: He will not even reach the exit(), as the header will redirect first

Comment: @SuperPeanut Actually code execution continues after a call to  `header()` he will just not see the results of the remaining execution. Otherwise how could you send more than one header

Comment: Thank you, I just tested inserting the form data into the database and it worked out fine.